# apply CSS only to a specific cshtml block

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am adding bootstrap.css to design some elements of a certain div without messing with the rest of the elements.

Example:

```
...code here...
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
</div>
...some more code here...
```

Importing bootstrap.css:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But when I run my code, the bootstrap.css messes with the rest of the elements. How can I import bootstrap.css that it will only apply on btn-group class?

Comment: Its not good practise but use !important for those element whom you want to use.

Comment: If you just need to style for btn-group, just add the css of that element to your current style sheet, don't need to import the whole bootstrap.css file.

Comment: @Darian: I was having doubts on this implementation since there is an existing bootstrap.css on our library and extracting the classes and ids that I needed is not a good practice because there will be code redundancy. But it seems I have no other choice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize Bootstrap before downloading to include the required parts only

1. go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
2. click "Toggle all" to uncheck all components check required components only e.g. 'Buttons'
3. go all the way down and click 'Compile and download'